# regex remove column "|" character

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How do I remove all the occurrences of the character `|` from a string with regex? I tried

```
string.replace(/|/gi,'');
```

but this does not seem to work...

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

the regex is `/\|/`, you have to escape `|` since in regex, `|` is used to declare [alternatives](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
string.replace(/\|/gi,'')
```

Need to escape it due to it being a special character. You use `\` to escape.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/DAQt9/)**

Answer (score 2):

The pipe has [special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in a regular expression, you need to escape it:

```
string.replace(/\|/g,'');
```

On a side note, you don't need to ignore casing when you're not dealing with letters.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this :

```
<script language="javascript">
document.write('A|A');
document.write('A|A'.replace('|','B'));
</script>
```

And the output is what you are looking for:

```
A|AABA
```

Comment: bah yeah sometimes I get so caught up in what the poster has for code I forget the simpler solutions +1. Only potential issue is if the poster happens to be doing some other replaces besides the pipe in the same line.

Comment: javascript replace will only replace the first instance of the `|` character, the OP specified global replied in his example.